# Как получить уровень громкости (dB) системный Windows микшер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, windows-10

Как можно получить текущий уровень в dB или процентах, например, когда слушаю музыку?

Вот процент этой шкалы (что зеленая), то есть когда что-то воспроизводиться и какой уровень громкости в процентах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Возьми эту либу https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio . Там получаешь стрим с параметром format = pyaudio.paInt16, as_loopback=True и остальными(посмотри в примерах и доках что там ещё нужно). Оттуда читаешь долю секунды и раскладываешь массив. находишь там разницу max - min - это будет амплитуда. Амплитуду*100 делишь на 2**16 - получится процент громкости этой доли секунды. Тут можно прикрутить audioop.max наверное чтоб не нарезать вручную

Comment: Можешь показать как это должно быть ??? Я загнусь проверять опять не удачный вариант... (скорее всего)

Comment: винды сейчас нет) да и вам не интересно будет если весь код напишу за вас...

Comment: очень давно писал по такому принципу.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1227396/384202) @eri представлю вариант реализации.

Если

> вам не интересно будет если весь код напишу за вас

то можете дальше не смотреть `:)`

### Компиляция библиотеки:

Клонируете репозиторий https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio и следуете инструкциям в `README`

Возможно, вам пригодится `Windows SDK`

### Реализация

Можете посмотреть пример на GitHub и относительно него писать своё решение.
А я предоставлю свой вариант:

```
import pyaudio

defaultFrames = 16

paObj = pyaudio.PyAudio()

try:
    defaultOutputDeviceHandle = paObj.get_default_output_device_info()
    #defaultOutputDeviceHandle = paObj.get_device_info_by_index(idx)
except IOError:
    print ("No default device available. Quitting...")
    exit(-1)


stream = paObj.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,
                    channels = defaultOutputDeviceHandle["maxOutputChannels"],
                    rate = int(defaultOutputDeviceHandle["defaultSampleRate"]),
                    input = True,
                    frames_per_buffer = defaultFrames,
                    input_device_index = defaultOutputDeviceHandle["index"],
                    as_loopback = True)

recordedFrames = list(stream.read(defaultFrames))

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

paObj.terminate()

joinedFrames = []
for i in range(0, len(recordedFrames), 2):
    joinedFrames.append(recordedFrames[i] << 8 | recordedFrames[i+1])


print((max(joinedFrames) - min(joinedFrames)) * 100 / (1 << 16))
```

В общем, здесь я открываю поток на стандартном устройстве вывода звука (оно должно поддерживать `LoopBack`), потом читаю некоторое количество данных.

Если стандартный девайс определяется неверно - используйте получение по индексу, приложение будет непереносимым, но для тестов пойдет. Как получить все девайсы с индексами? Код для этого есть в примере на GitHub (этот код записывает звук, но сначала предлагает выбрать устройство, там и отображаются индексы).

Так как это 16 битный звук - массив байтов нужно преобразовать в массив двухбайтовых чисел, проще говоря сделать так:

```
short twoByteNumber = (firstByte << 8 | secondByte);
```

Далее пользуемся формулой, представленной @eri:

```
amplitude = (max - min)
volumeLevel = (amplitude * 100) / (1 << 16)
```

*1 << 16 == 2 ^ 16*

Comment: Спасибо !!! !!!

Comment: А что если такая ошибка появляется?
[Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels

Comment: @Kickwall убедитесь, что `defaultOutputDeviceHandle` ссылается на верное устройство (то, громкость которого вы хотите замерить). И приведите, пожалуйста, содержимое `defaultOutputDeviceHandle["maxOutputChannels"]`

Comment: @Стас `defaultOutputDeviceHandle["maxOutputChannels"]` = 8

Comment: @Kickwall попробуйте подобрать количество каналов вручную или задать вопрос о этой проблеме. Честно говоря, я не знаю, что могло случиться

Comment: Нарезка фрейма у вас конечно жесть)

Comment: По замечаниям к коду: 1) если брать один канал, то буфер будет в разы меньше - проще обсчитывать. 2) перегонять в list не нужно. 3) младший байт можно  откинуть - это 0.2% , проще всего это сделать срезом с шагом. 4) перегонять в новый массив не обязательно.

Comment: Еще стоит учесть знак если формат знаковый... Я уж забыл какой там

Answer (score 2):

Хорошая библиотека [pycaw](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw) для работы с аудио под Windows. Из [usage](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw#usage):

```py
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
volume.GetMute()
volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel()
volume.GetVolumeRange()
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-20.0, None)
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло !

Comment: @ПавелБиза добавляйте в вопрос, что пробовали, что получилось, а что - нет, какие ошибки... "не помогло" не поможет ))

Comment: GetMasterVolumeLevel это синяя стрелка, а ему надо зеленую полоску.

Comment: Вот именно, облазил все и вся и так ничего толком и не нашел, самое прикольное что под C# есть одна dll-ка с помощью нее получалось получать спокойно эти значения и переводить их в проценты, а под python как не странно получить в рельно туже секунду какой у тебя сейчас скажем процент или dB на выходе на динамиках нигде не нашел.